# MS CRM 2011 Create Record and get it's Guid

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I write a plugin for creating records and I'm facing following problem:

I have 2 entities. Entity1 and Entity2. Entity2 has a n-1 relationship to Entity1 and got also a lookupfield to Entity1 on it's form. In my plugin code I create an Entity1 record, and after that I want to create an Entity2 record with the lookupfield (to Entity1) filled with the just created record of Entity1. But I got an error. My code looks like this:

```
Entity entity1 = new Entity("new_entity1");
//Here I'm filling my entity1's fields
Guid entity1Id = service.Create(entity1);

Entity entity2 = new Entity("new_entity2");
//Here I'm filling my entity2's fields
entity2 ["new_entity1id"] = new EntityReference("new_entity1",entity1Id);

service.Create(entity2);
```

I'm new to CRM development so I can't really recognize the problem. I assume that maybe everything is created when the plugin code finishes, so the Entity1 record is not created by the time I create the Entity2 record, but it's just my assumption.

Any help would be great.

The error message:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx]]: An error occured in the AccountCreateHandler plug-inDetail:  <OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">   <ErrorCode>-2147220891</ErrorCode>   <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <d2p1:key>OperationStatus</d2p1:key>
      <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">0</d2p1:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>   </ErrorDetails>   <Message>An error occured in the AccountCreateHandler plug-in</Message>   <Timestamp>2011-12-09T14:17:22.2773373Z</Timestamp>   <InnerFault i:nil="true" />   <TraceText>

[Execute_Buchen: Execute_Buchen.Class1] [dc2f71e8-b216-e111-b59f-00155d0a3339: Execute_Buchen.Class1: Update of new_entity0 START:IPlugin.Execute

</TraceText> </OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Comment: can you post the exception you are getting ? What you have is correct. the plugin executes synchronously (provided that was ticked on the plugin registration tool) So it will create entity 1 first then entity 2 with the guid

Comment: Are you using the correct entity names and fields? in the execption it says `Update of new_entity0` in comparison to the code you posted?

Comment: yes I renamed it to "new_entity0" myself for this postin. This is also not one of the entity of my question(entity1 or entity2). Fact is that if I remove the line : 
entity2 ["new_entity1id"] = new EntityReference("new_entity1",entity1Id);
posted on my question the records get created, of course with empty lookupfield on entity2 record

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it this way instead.

```
entity2.Attributes.Add("new_entity1id",new EntityReference("new_entity1",entity1Id));
```

As for the exception if it's still thrown after trying the above I can only think of two things.

In the line `entity2 ["new_entity1id"] = new EntityReference("new_entity1",entity1Id);`

Either `new_entity1id` is the wrong field name for `entity2`

or

That lookup field looks up to a different entity and trying to save the `EntityReference` you create is throwing an Exception.

Comment: Either of the two reasons posted here look like good candidates to me for the cause of the exception